# How to order user by registration date using WP_User_Query

Tags: wordpress

I've to modify a query used in a Wordpress Theme because it's not orders users by their registration date.
I need to shown last subscribed users.
This query uses like ordering arg:

```
$args['orderby'] = 'rand'
```

What's it means?

I sobstituite this code row with

```
$args['orderby'] = 'user_registered'
```

but users shown aren't last subscribed users.

Can you help me, please?
Thank's!

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It's working.

```
// define the pre_get_users callback 

function action_pre_user_query( $u_query ) { 

    $u_query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'user_registered';
    $u_query->query_vars['order'] = 'DESC';

}
add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'action_pre_user_query');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args['orderby'] = 'registered'
```

try this